# Login failure for "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have created a project level sql-server connection for my SSIS project. There are multiple packages which utilise this connection and it works perfectly fine. However, I have a new package which contains an "Execute SQL Task". This task also utilises the same connection but throws an error saying "login failed for user".

Answer (score 1):

It might be one of these things:

- The **Protection level** property that is set to DontSaveSensitive, meaning the password doesn't get saved. You can choose to change it to **EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey**. Although I wouldnt suggest this when you deliver the project to Deployment server
- If you are using **package configuration** and saving the connection string to a XML File (for example) the password won't get saved, you have to add it manually. Something like: *;Password=someReallyCoolPassword;*
- Even if you do at the password manually, it can still have some problems. I believe it can be that the word "Password" is sensitive itself, and even if you have protection level as DontSaveSensitive, when the package read the XML File, it wont read the password value. I have no idea why, but have to put a blank space before Password, like this: *; Password=someReallyCoolPassword;* and it will work, although your connection could be seen if someone hover the mouse over the connection manager.

If you could add more information about how you are handling your connection, I could give you a mroe specific answer